# Linux/Ubuntu based message queue

Tags: 19.10

i'm totally new to Ubuntu/Linux based OS, and right now I'm using Ubuntu 19.10, so to make things short, I'm gonna need to develop an application that talk to other application via message queue, is there any build-in message queue offered by Linux/Ubuntu? I've used to develop similar application in Windows based using MSMQ.

thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

There are two common message queue implementations in UNIX. One is part of the SYS V API, the other one is part of POSIX.

See the documentation about POSIX Message Queue:
https://users.pja.edu.pl/~jms/qnx/help/watcom/clibref/mq_overview.html
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man7/mq_overview.7.html